# Scanf not reading newline while using "%c%c"

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C language and recently solving a question which asks to use %c%c to validate y or n entered by the user,I wanted to know why this program is giving wrong output if I type characters like w or e, then it doesn't seem to read the newline character.

```
void clearKeyboard(void)
{
    while (getchar() != '\n')   ; 

}
int yes(void){
    char char1;
    char char2;
    int result=-1;
    
    do{
        scanf("%c%c",&char1,&char2);
        if (char2!='\n'){
            clearKeyboard();
            printf("*** INVALID input *** <Please enter again>: ");

        }
        else{
            if(char1=='y'||char1=='Y'){
                result=1;
            }
            else if(char1=='n'||char1=='N'){
                result=0;
            }
            else{
                clearKeyboard();
                printf("*** INVALID input *** <Please enter again>: ");

            }
        }

    }while(char2!='\n');
    return result;
    
}
```

Comment: It's reading the newline just fine. Perhaps you should reconsider the condition in the while?

Comment: What is "wrong output"? Concretely what is outputted and what is expected?

Comment: `clearKeyboard` is flawed. if there is nothing in the input buffer, then `clearKeyboard` waits until the user enters something.

Comment: So if you enter 'w' followed by newline, it still calls `clearKeyboard` even though it is already at the end of the line?

Comment: Don't call `clearKeyboard();` on "bad" input in the `else` as you have already consumed the newline. It is guaranteed to be in `char2` because of `if (char2!='\n'){`.

Comment: Thanks Johnny Mopp, your suggestion worked for me : ) .

Comment: My recommendation to you -- although this may not seem helpful at first -- is that if you are just learning C, and if you must use `scanf`, you should *never* use the `%c` format.  (At all, let alone twice like this.)  `scanf` is supposed to be simple, but `%c` is just too confusing.  There's no practical use for it.  Seriously.  And although you may lose points for skipping this particular question on your assignment, you'll be better for it in the end.

Comment: Thank you so much @SteveSummit . so better to use %s right? but here i was constrained to use the %c%c format.

Comment: @AbhijitDP Yes, `%s` would be better -- a little better.  I understand that your instructor wants you to learn about `scanf`, so you don't have a lot of choice here.  But from my perspective -- I've been programming in C for almost 40 years -- the `scanf` function is **useless**.  I *never* use it, in *any* of the programs I write.

Comment: In my opinion, for your instructor to be teaching you about `scanf` and `%c%c`, would be like taking a cooking class, and the instructor teaches you how to balance an egg on the point of a knife.  It's not easy to do, and there might be some satisfaction if by some miracle you succeed in doing it, but it has no practical use whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` does read the newline. Your code is simple wrong and overly complicated.

Also you cannot "clear the keyboard", at least not with standard C functions.

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int yes(void) {
  char char1;
  int result = -1;

  do {
    scanf("%c", &char1);
    if (char1 == '\n') {
      continue;  // if it a newline, ignore it and continue
    }

    if (char1 == 'y' || char1 == 'Y') {
      result = 1;   // it's a yes
    }
    else if (char1 == 'n' || char1 == 'N') {
      result = 0;   // it's a no
    }
    else
    {
      // anything else than yes or no
      printf("*** INVALID input *** <Please enter again>: ");
    }
  } while (result != 0 && result != 1);  // repeat until yes or no

  return result;
}

int main()
{
  while (1)
  {
    printf("yes = %d\n", yes());
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir, Actually the instructions are to check if the second character entered is a newline and if it is then check if the user entered y or n.else discard it by saying its invalid.

Comment: @AbhijitDP these instructions are  flawed and they are somewhat like: "You need to cut this loaf of bread into slices, but you are not allowed to use a knife but only a fork".

Comment: I agree to you @Jabberwocky

Comment: `scanf` is like a learner's bicycle with square training wheels.  And `%c` is a rock in the bearings of one of those wheels.  (And don't get me started on `%[...]`.)